# How to implement Paypal Rest API in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have to implement Paypal REST API in my rails project(Rails 6) but I am very confused about how to implement it.

While searching it on google I found the below gem but that SDK is deprecated:-
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK

I also tried the below sample but it is also using the `'v1/payments/payment`' API which I think has been deprecated:-
https://github.com/yosriady/paypal-rest-sample-app

And I am also confused about the 'PayPal Checkout v2' and 'Active Merchant'. Your help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the links in the deprecation notice? The Orders v2 SDK for Ruby is https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Ruby-SDK

If you are looking for a front-end UI demo pattern to pair with it, use https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Thanks for help...can I use the REST API v2  without using the Smart Paypal Payment Buttons?

Comment: For a worse experience. You can configure it to display just the PayPal Checkout if that's all you want, or try the horizontal layout which will show at most two options depending on the user's country and if they have venmo on that device

Comment: Thanks but I am not able to pair up Orders v2 SDK for Ruby with the Smart Paypal Payment Buttons any suggestions on how to combine it?

Comment: You need two routes, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction'. There is a guide at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

Comment: Yes I have created two routes and inside 'Set Up Transaction' I am calling the Paypal create order API but my client-side jquery function 'createOrder' is not getting the response from the controller. it is always showing some default value and not able to get the value of orderID.

Comment: client-side 'createOrder' function...createOrder: function() {
     return fetch('/orders', {
       method: 'post',
       headers: {
         'content-type': 'application/json'
       }
     }).then(function(res) {
       return res;
     }).then(function(data) {
       return data.orderID; // Use the same key name for order ID on the client and server
     });
   },

Comment: Use the example in the second link

Comment: Sorry to bother you again what about if I want to implement the payouts do I still need to implement the above steps?

Comment: That is a completely separate integration that has nothing to do with any of the above, but there is a Payouts-Ruby-SDK

Comment: Thanks..Got it.. I was following the PayPal rest api documentation https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/  and I am still confused about the first step how the user will be redirected to the Paypal so that he can sign in and authorize the payment. Any idea regarding this?

Comment: Payments V2 is for managing already completed payments. Redirection is a very poor choice for modern web design. Sign in and authorization takes place in the second link I shared. None of this has anything to do with Payouts, which does not have a sign in and authorization step.  It's possible you are looking for the custom 'payee' variable rather than payouts.

Comment: But i can see a Deprecation notice: The /v1/payments endpoint is deprecated. Use the /v2/payments endpoint instead. what does it mean?

Comment: It means what it says, but (a) nowhere where we talking about v1 Payments, and (b) v2 Payments does not create new payments

Comment: Sorry i am bothering you again and again...so it means I just have to use the Checkout-Ruby-SDK for the payment using https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-Ruby-SDK link and I have to integrate the Paypal smart buttons which will take care of payment process.

Comment: [Here is a list](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/) of current PayPal REST SDKs, including Checkout v2 and Payouts.

Answer (score 1):

[This tutorial](https://www.davidangulo.xyz/simple-paypal-checkout-in-ruby-on-rails-using-orders-api-v2/) from May 2020 is promising. It describes "Simple Paypal checkout in Ruby on Rails using Orders API v2".

I implemented it today. It took only a couple of hours, and I can confirm that it works.

I was worried about how to insert the actual order data in the `create_order` action of the tutorial example, but it turns out that the session is available, so I can read my `cart_id` etc. from the session.

I added `&currency=EUR&disable-funding=credit,card` to the button script to set the currency and hide the card payment button. I also had to replace 'USD' with 'EUR' in the `create_order` action.